# Force onchange to a specific value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML-code and Javascript that looks lik this:

```
<td>Item Category</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="item_category_selection" onchange="item_category(value)">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <?php
                            $type_result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT ItemCategory FROM ".$dmt_objects." ORDER BY ItemCategory ASC ");
                            while($type_array = mysql_fetch_array($type_result)){
                                if($type_array['ItemCategory'] !== "N/A" && $type_array['ItemCategory'] !== "Item"){
                                echo "<option>".$type_array['ItemCategory']."</option>";
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

This results in a list with different options, however they don't have any values assinged to them. It looks like this:

```
<select id="item_category_selection" onchange="item_category(value)">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>Alt 1</option>
                        <option>Alt 2</option>
```

The function that is called looks like this:

```
function item_category(val){
        selected_item_category = $("#item_category_selection").val();

        document.getElementById("sel_target").innerHTML = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "find_objects.php",
            data: {selected_item_category:selected_item_category, selected_project:selected_project},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data){
                $('#sel_target').append("<option value='Select value' >Select Value</option>");
                $('#sel_target').append("<option value='PAINT ALL' >Show All</option>");
                var array_length = data.length;

                for(var i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
                    var ItemName = data[i].ItemName;
                    var DatabaseID = data[i].DatabaseID;

                    $('#sel_target').append("<option value='"+DatabaseID+"' >" + ItemName + "</option>");



                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, I want to force it to one option, and call the function. How do I do that? When you click on a different button, I want the Itemcategory to be changed to a specific one.

Comment: First of all give value to every option and change onchange="item_category(value)" to onchange="item_category(this.value)"

Comment: Second, you won't need to send the `value` with the parameters because you are not using it. You get the value from `selected_item_category = $("#item_category_selection").val();`

Comment: ok, but how do I set the item category manually? something like item_category_selection = "Alt 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
var setValue = 'Alt 1';
$('#item_category_selection')
  .val(setValue)  // set the value of the <select>
  .change()       // call the 'onchange' function
;
```

```js
function item_category(v) {
  $('#output').text('value: ' + v);
}

function buttonClick() {
  var setValue = 'Alt 1';
  $('#item_category_selection')
    .val(setValue)
    .change()
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="item_category_selection" onchange="item_category(value)">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option>Alt 1</option>
  <option>Alt 2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="buttonClick()" value="try it">

<div id="output"></div>
```